# How to perform the same t-test in a for loop?

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a database with columns *theme* (value 0 or 1), *level* (value 1 to 9) and *startTime* (double value). For every level, I want to perform a t-test on the startTime values. Here is my code:

```
database <- read.csv("database.csv")
themeData <- database[database$theme == 1, ]
noThemeData <- database[database$theme == 0, ]

for (i in 1:9) {
  x <- themeData[themeData$level == i, ]
  y <- noThemeData[noThemeData$level == i, ]
  t.test(x$startTime,y$startTime,
         alternative = "less")
}
```

Unfortunately, no t-tests are being executed. In the end, x and y simply get the value for i=9. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Right now you aren't doing anything with them in the loop. Do you just want to print the results? Then do so in the loop: `print(t.test(...))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is doing busy work: it is doing the calculations of the `t.test`, but *since `for` loops always discard their implied results*, you aren't storing it anywhere. You would have had to use a vector or list (pre-allocated is always better) like so:

```
res <- replicate(9, NULL)
for (i in 1:9) {
  x <- themeData[themeData$level == i, ]
  y <- noThemeData[noThemeData$level == i, ]
  res[[i]] <- t.test(x$startTime,y$startTime,
                     alternative = "less")
}
res[[2]]
```

This can be "good enough" in that it is saving all test "results objects" in a `list` for later processing/consumption. A slightly better method is to use one of the `*apply` functions; the first two I think of that are directly applicable here (`lapply`, `sapply(..., simplify=FALSE)`) have various minor advantages, frankly you can choose either.

```
res <- lapply(c(4, 6, 8), function(thiscyl) {
  am0 <- subset(mtcars, am == 0 & cyl == thiscyl)
  am1 <- subset(mtcars, am == 1 & cyl == thiscyl)
  t.test(am0$mpg, am1$mpg)
})
```

This is especially beneficial if (unlike here) the tests take a long time: you perform the test *and preserve the models*, so you can so lots of things to the results without having to rerun the tests. For instance, if you wanted just the p-values:

```
sapply(res, `[`, "p.value")
# $p.value
# [1] 0.01801712
# $p.value
# [1] 0.187123
# $p.value
# [1] 0.7038727
```

or more tersely:

```
sapply(res, `[[`, "p.value")
# [1] 0.01801712 0.18712303 0.70387268
```

Another example, the confidence intervals, in a matrix:

```
t(sapply(res, `[[`, "conf.int"))
#           [,1]      [,2]
# [1,] -9.232108 -1.117892
# [2,] -3.916068  1.032735
# [3,] -2.339549  1.639549
```

You can always look at a single model with, say, `res[[2]]`, but if you need to see all of them you can use just `res` and see the whole gamut.

```
res[[2]]
#   Welch Two Sample t-test
# data:  am0$mpg and am1$mpg
# t = -1.5606, df = 4.4055, p-value = 0.1871
# alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
# 95 percent confidence interval:
#  -3.916068  1.032735
# sample estimates:
# mean of x mean of y 
#  19.12500  20.56667
```